# Xcode11 beta6 run 'xcodebuild test' in terminal ,always appear crash Method is 'primaryInstrumentsServerWithError'

Tags: mac

Details:  [DVTiPhoneSimulator -primaryInstrumentsServer was called from the main thread
Object:   
Method:   -primaryInstrumentsServerWithError:
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Have you managed to resolve it or gather any new information since posting here?

Comment: No, I still can't figure it out

Comment: Me neither. I reported a bug using Feedback Assistant just now. FB7285474

Comment: I did it one week ago,but never received reply.

Comment: Disabling parallel testing seems to improve things a bit for me, so maybe you could try that out if you haven't already?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,and how to disabling parallel testing ?

Comment: I disabled parallel testing,but it not work for me.

Comment: @vrutberg Have you heard anything regarding the bug report?

Comment: @Jesper No, not yet. However, the bug report says: `Recent Similar Reports: More than 10`. So I guess we're not alone. :-)